# Macvtap connectivity lost after a few hours?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, vlan

I setup a macvtap interface like this:

```
ip link add link eth0 vlan type macvlan mode bridge
ip address add 10.0.0.17 dev vlan
ip link set dev vlan up
ip route flush dev eth0
ip route flush dev vlan
ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev vlan metric 0
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1
ip link add link eth0 name vtap address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx type macvtap mode bridge
ip link set vtap up
ip address flush eth0
ip address flush vtap
dhclient -v vtap
ip address flush vtap
```

And it works fine for a couple of hours. But after that, any connections to the DHCP (macvtap) IP will start going to the host machine instead. So if I connect to the IP at port 80 for example, I will see a page served by the host instead of the VM.

I am trying to understand why it stops working. At first I thought maybe the DHCP lease expired, and `dhclient` is not renewing it. But the leasetime is 24 hours, and this problem starts earlier than that, sometimes in less than 10 hours.

So what can be causing the `macvtap` interface to stop working?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145804/discussion-on-question-by-maestro-macvtap-connectivity-lost-after-a-few-hours); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `dhclient` was started, it was the only one using the `macvtap` interface. But when `dhclient` was sending a packet in order to renew the lease after many hours, it broke macvtap because by that time the guest was also using the interface. And both host and guest cannot use the same interface simultanously.

If a totally different program had just sended a random packet over that interface from the host, for example a simple `ping` packet, the same would have happened. So this problem was not related to DHCP in any way.